# Crop a box around n percentile of maximum values

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, crop, edge-detection

Given a binary image, how do I box around the majority of the white pixels? For example, consider the following image:
[image: image processing to edge detection]

As canny segmentation results in a binary image, I thought I could use np.nonzero to identify the location of the points, and then draw a box around it. I have the following function to identify the location of the bounding box but its not working as intended (as you can see by the box in the image above):

```
def get_bounding_box(image,thresh=0.95):
    nonzero_indices = np.nonzero(image)
    min_row, max_row = np.min(nonzero_indices[0]), np.max(nonzero_indices[0])
    min_col, max_col = np.min(nonzero_indices[1]), np.max(nonzero_indices[1])
    box_size = max_row - min_row + 1, max_col - min_col + 1
    print(box_size)
    #box_size_thresh = (int(box_size[0] * thresh), int(box_size[1] * thresh))
    box_size_thresh = (int(box_size[0]), int(box_size[1]))
    #coordinates of the box that contains 95% of the highest pixel values
    top_left = (min_row + int((box_size[0] - box_size_thresh[0]) / 2), min_col + int((box_size[1] - box_size_thresh[1]) / 2))
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + box_size_thresh[0], top_left[1] + box_size_thresh[1])
    print((top_left[0], top_left[1]), (bottom_right[0], bottom_right[1]))
    return (top_left[0], top_left[1]), (bottom_right[0], bottom_right[1])
```

and using the following code to get the coords and draw the box as follows:

```
seg= canny_segmentation(gray)
bb_thresh = get_bounding_box(seg,0.95)
im_crop = gray[bb_thresh[0][1]:bb_thresh[1][1],bb_thresh[0][0]:bb_thresh[1][0]]
```

why is this code not giving me the right top left / bottom right coordinates?

I have a example colab workbook here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15TNVPsYeZOCiOB51I-geVXgGFyIp5PjU?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the order of the coordinates returned from `get_bounding_box`:

`return (top_left[0], top_left[1]), (bottom_right[0], bottom_right[1])`
Applies the following ordering:
(`y0`, `x0`), (`y1`, `x1`)
When `y` is the row and `x` is column.

When returned coordinates are used by `im_crop = gray[bb_thresh[0][1]:bb_thresh[1][1], bb_thresh[0][0]:bb_thresh[1][0]]` the **rows and columns are switched up**.

---

For avoiding confusion I recommend storing the coordinates in `x0`, `y0`, `x1`, `y1` first:

```
(y0, x0), (y1, x1) = bb_thresh
```

Then use the coordinates in the correct order:

```
im_crop = gray[y0:y1, x0:x1]
```

---

For testing, we may also draw a rectangle using `cv2.rectangle`:

```
cv2.rectangle(bgr_image, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Part of the confusion is related to the fact the NumPy array indexing is `(y, x)` and OpenCV "point" coordinate convention is `(x, y)`

---

Code sample (not using Google Colab):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def get_bounding_box(image, thresh=0.95):
    nonzero_indices = np.nonzero(image)
    min_row, max_row = np.min(nonzero_indices[0]), np.max(nonzero_indices[0])
    min_col, max_col = np.min(nonzero_indices[1]), np.max(nonzero_indices[1])
    box_size = max_row - min_row + 1, max_col - min_col + 1
    print(box_size)
    #box_size_thresh = (int(box_size[0] * thresh), int(box_size[1] * thresh))
    box_size_thresh = (int(box_size[0]), int(box_size[1]))
    #coordinates of the box that contains 95% of the highest pixel values
    top_left = (min_row + int((box_size[0] - box_size_thresh[0]) / 2), min_col + int((box_size[1] - box_size_thresh[1]) / 2))
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + box_size_thresh[0], top_left[1] + box_size_thresh[1])
    print((top_left[0], top_left[1]), (bottom_right[0], bottom_right[1]))
    return (top_left[0], top_left[1]), (bottom_right[0], bottom_right[1])  # Return format is (y0, x0), (y1, x1), when y is the row and x is the column

def canny_segmentation(img, low_threshold=100, high_threshold=200):
    edges = cv2.Canny(img, low_threshold, high_threshold)
    return edges

gray = cv2.imread('small_grayscale_image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read input image as Grayscale

seg = canny_segmentation(gray, 300, 320) # Use high thresholds - for testing
bb_thresh = get_bounding_box(seg, 0.95)
#im_crop = gray[bb_thresh[0][1]:bb_thresh[1][1], bb_thresh[0][0]:bb_thresh[1][0]]
(y0, x0), (y1, x1) = bb_thresh  # Store coordinates in intermediate variables in order to avoid confusion.
im_crop = gray[y0:y1, x0:x1]

# Draw green rectangle for testing
bgr_image = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.rectangle(bgr_image, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('bgr_image', bgr_image)
cv2.imshow('seg', seg)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

`bgr_image.png`:
[image]

`im_crop`:
[image]

`seg`:
[image]

`small_grayscale_image` (input image):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the top left and bottom right coordinates of the bounding box are not correctly calculated in the get_bounding_box function. The problem might lie in the calculation of top_left and bottom_right. The indices for the top left and bottom right coordinates of the bounding box should be calculated based on the min_row, max_row, min_col, max_col values, and not box_size_thresh.

Here's a corrected version of the code:

```
def get_bounding_box(image,thresh=0.95):
    nonzero_indices = np.nonzero(image)
    min_row, max_row = np.min(nonzero_indices[0]), np.max(nonzero_indices[0])
    min_col, max_col = np.min(nonzero_indices[1]), np.max(nonzero_indices[1])

    top_left = (min_row, min_col)
    bottom_right = (max_row, max_col)
    return top_left, bottom_right
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the neater code, mine is defiantly messier! but this is the same result as my original code. Turns out I just needed to transpose the image as the coordinates were messed up due to that ```nonzero_indices = np.nonzero(image.T)```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to transpose the image before getting the coordinates, a simple .T did the trick

```
nonzero_indices = np.nonzero(image.T)
```

Comment: Can you please explain why do you have to transpose the image? Isn't it just hiding the real issue?